# Async Await fails in NODE.JS when client connects to server

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await

When my React client connects to the server :

**index.js :**

```
var mongoAPI = require("./MongoDB/mongodb.js");

app.get("/getImages" , async function(req,res) {
  var db_images = await mongoAPI.getAllImages();  // this is undefined
  console.log(db_images);
  res.json(db_images);
});
```

It goes to the database :

**mongodb.js :**

```
getAllImages = async () => {
  await MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
    if (err) {
      throw err;
    }
    var dbo = db.db("PicturesDB");
    dbo
      .collection("Images")
      .find({})
      .toArray(function(err, result) {
        if (err) {
          // res.send(err);
          return err;
        } else {
          // res.send(JSON.stringify(result));
          return JSON.stringify(result);
        }
      });
  });
};


module.exports = {
    ...
    ... 
  getAllImages: getAllImages
};
```

However `db_images` is always undefined , even though that the data returns properly (I checked with "console.log' in the `getAllImages` method).

Where did I go wrong with the request ?

Comment: ***await*** dbo.collection().find({})

Comment: `await` only  does something useful when you `await` a promise.   `await MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {...})`  is not awaiting a promise.  Same issue in your `dbo.collection().find()`.  You MUST use the promise interface in your database with `await`, not the plain callback interface.  `await` has no magic asynchronous powers.  All it knows how to do is monitor a promise.  If you don't give it a promise, it does nothing useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current code is attempting to use `await`, but you aren't using the promise interface in the database.  With Mongodb, when you pass a regular callback to something like `.connect()` or `.toArray()`, it does not return a promise so then your `await` does nothing useful.  But, if you don't pass that callback at all (and are using a newish version of the database library), then it returns a promise that you can use.

Here's what I would suggest:

```
getAllImages = async (url) => {
   const db =  await MongoClient.connect(url);
   const dbo = db.db("PicturesDB");
   const result = await dbo.collection("Images").find({}).toArray();
   return JSON.stringify(result);
}
```

This uses the promise interface on `.connect()` and awaits that.  If the connection fails, the promise will reject and `await` will throw which will cause the `async` function to reject the promise it already returned so the caller will properly see the error.

And, keep in mind that when we do `return JSON.stringify(result);` in an `async` function, that is telling the interpreter that we want `JSON.stringify(result)` to become the resolved value of the promise that the function has already returned (all `async` functions return a promise).

---

And, then you need proper error handling in your request handler in case something goes wrong with `getAllImages()`:

```
app.get("/getImages" , async function(req,res) {
    try {
        const db_images = await mongoAPI.getAllImages();
        console.log(db_images);
        res.json(db_images);
    } catch(e) {
        // database error
        console.log(e);
        res.status(500).send("database error");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The `getAllImages` function doesn't return your value. It just returns what the `connect` method returns.

Since you are using `await` to call the `getAllImages` function, return a promise and resolve it with your value.

```
getAllImages = async () => {

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

      MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {

       if (err) {
         reject(err)
       }

       var dbo = db.db("PicturesDB");

       dbo
        .collection("Images")
        .find({})
        .toArray(function(err, result) {
          if (err) {

           reject(err)

        } else {

          resolve(JSON.stringify(result));
        }
      });
  });



  })

};
```

However, the most accurate pattern is to use the native promise interface of your library as pointed out by jfriend00 in a comment.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use the actual promise interface built into the database library?

Comment: Of course. But I just tried to point out where the OPs code fails. Thanks.

Comment: And, then you suggested a fix that is the wrong fix.  The right fix is to use the actual promise interface in the database and then they can actually use `await` properly.

Comment: I just checked docs. The connect has no built in promise. So, anyway the OP will have to return promise created by himself. The `find` of course could be synchronous.

Comment: Check [the docs here](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.2/api/MongoClient.html#.connect).  If you are using a recent version of the library and you don't pass a callback, then `.connect()` returns a promise.  You can also use a promise with `.find()`.

Answer (score 1):

We should not mix aysnc await with callbacks, i have written the code only with async await, and mongoclient now returns promise.

```
getAllImages = async (url) => {

 const db =  await MongoClient.connect(url);
    if (!db)
      throw "An error occurred";
    var dbo = db.db("PicturesDB");
    const result = await dbo.collection("Images").find({}).toArray()
    if (!result) 
        return "error occurred";
    else
        return JSON.stringify(result);
}
```

Comment: Thanks , but you're not returning a promise , you `return JSON.stringify(result);`

Comment: Every async function returns a promise, so when we return, it returns a promise